# SQL Join Query - How to get values from right table in a Full Outer Join when NULL in the left

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in SQL with matching field names. I am trying to join the tables so if the left table IS NULL then it uses the right table's value.

For context this is using two tables for video game sales, the left table is for PlayStation and the right table is for Xbox. Some games are Xbox exclusive and when I join the tables, the title field is NULL.

The current code I have is below. How do I add a statement to select the Game Title from the Xbox table when the Playstation Table does not have a value. Or is there an easier way to merge the tables together? The tables are identical in field names.

```
    SELECT
  p.Game,
  p.Genre,
  p.Publisher,
  p.North_America AS ps_na,
  p.Europe AS ps_eur,
  p.Japan AS ps_japan,
  p.Rest_of_World AS ps_row,
  x.North_America AS xbox_na,
  x.Europe AS xbox_eur,
  x.Japan AS xbox_japan,
  x.Rest_of_World AS xbox_row,

FROM 
  games.ps4 AS p -- Selecting the ps4 table

  FULL JOIN 
    games.xboxone AS x -- Joining the Xbox One table
    USING(Game)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions)

Comment: Try: `COALESCE(p.Game, x.Game)`, will pick the first non-null value.